# Base Conversion Problem

Tags: c++, modulo, radix, itoa

I'm trying to convert an integer to a string right now, and I'm having a problem.

I've gotten the code written and working for the most part, but it has a small flaw when carrying to the next place. It's hard to describe, so I'll give you an example. Using base 26 with a character set consisting of the lowercase alphabet:

0 = "a"
1 = "b"
2 = "c"

...

25 = "z"
26 = "ba" (This should equal "aa")

It seems to skip the character at the zero place in the character set in certain situations.

The thing that's confusing me is I see nothing wrong with my code. I've been working on this for too long now, and I still can't figure it out.

```
char* charset = (char*)"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int charsetLength = strlen(charset);

unsigned long long num = 5678; // Some random number, it doesn't matter
std::string key

do
{
    unsigned int remainder = (num % charsetLength);
    num /= charsetLength;

    key.insert(key.begin(), charset[remainder]);

} while(num);
```

I have a feeling the function is tripping up over the modulo returning a zero, but I've been working on this so long, I can't figure out how it's happening. Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: The fact that the generated string is little endian is irrelevant for my application.

Comment: Sidenote: Your choice of data types is dubious. Why isn't `charset` a `const char*`? (That would rid you of the C-style cast.) Why isn't `charsetlength` a `std::size_t` -- which is the type returned by `std::strlen()`. And if `num` is an `unsigned long long`, how would (on common platforms) the result of dividing it by 26 fit into an `unsigned int`?

Comment: I more or less wrote this code on the fly as an example, though your points are valid and appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want (the numbering used by excel for columns, A, B, .. Z, AA, AB, ...) this is a based notation able to represent numbers starting from 1.  The 26 digits have values 1, 2, ... 26 and the base is 26. So A has value 1, Z value 26, AA value 27...  Computing this representation is very similar to the normal reprentation you just need to adjust for the offset of 1 instead of 0.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

std::string base26(unsigned long v)
{
    char const digits[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    size_t const base = sizeof(digits) - 1;
    char result[sizeof(unsigned long)*CHAR_BIT + 1];
    char* current = result + sizeof(result);
    *--current = '\0';

    while (v != 0) {
        v--;
        *--current = digits[v % base];
        v /= base;
    }
    return current;
}

// for testing
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        unsigned long value = std::strtol(argv[i], 0, 0);
        std::cout << value << " = " << base26(value) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running with 1 2 26 27 52 53 676 677 702 703 gives

```
1 = A
2 = B
26 = Z
27 = AA
52 = AZ
53 = BA
676 = YZ
677 = ZA
702 = ZZ
703 = AAA
```

Comment: This example gave me exactly what I needed to fix my own code, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that 'a' == 0.

In other words, 'aa' is not the answer, because that is really 00. 'ba' is the correct answer because b = '1', so that makes it 10 in base 26, which is 26 in decimal.

Your code is correct, you just seem to be misunderstanding it.

Comment: Ah, yes. This makes sense. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The same way you fix the wrong representation of ten as "10" in decimal representation instead of "00".  In other words, there is nothing to fix.  Your code outputs the correct value.  For example, after 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 you get 10, not 00 in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a=1 and z=0 so you have abc...z just as in decimal 1234...90

Compare it to decimal system:9 is followed by 10 and not by 01!

Answer (score 0):

To get Aprogrammers solution to compile on my system (I'm using gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) I needed to add headers;`#include <climits> #include<cstdlib>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've queued an edit to Stuart's answer to add those includes. In future when you see a problem with an answer like that, I suggest you click the "edit" button to edit the answer directly, rather than posting another answer, to make sure everyone can see your change.